# Error al capturar valores de EditText Android Studio con Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo un problema al tratar de capturar los valores de **EditText** en mi fragmento.

```js
class login_email_fragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var emailEditText: EditText
    lateinit var passwordEditText: EditText
    lateinit var btn_login: Button

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_email_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        emailEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.emailEditText)
        passwordEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText)
        btn_login = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_login)

        val email: String = emailEditText.text.toString().trim()
        val password: String= passwordEditText.text.toString().trim()

        btn_login.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "email: $email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
}
```

Como pueden ver con normalidad estoy llamando los **id's** de los editText pero al tratar de mostrar en el **Toast** Lo unico que me muestra solo es **"email:"** sin mostrar el valor de la constante **email**. Cuando le quito el **toString()** a la variable **email** normal me muestra el email pero realmente no debería de ser asi. Por favor si alguien me podría ayudar. Le agradecería de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tu variable `email` solo se llama una vez, es decir, cuando creaste el fragment en el método `onViewCreated` y ahi le asignas el valor de tu ediText. Pero cuando vuelves a escribir ya no le estas asignando ningun valor a tu variable `email`. Si deseas que tu variable `email` tome el valor de tu edittext podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    emailEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.emailEditText)
    passwordEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText)
    btn_login = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_login)


    val password: String= passwordEditText.text.toString().trim()

    btn_login.setOnClickListener {
        val email: String = emailEditText.text.toString().trim()
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "email: $email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

No olvides lo siguiente del método `toString()` :
 Retorna una representación en forma de String de un objeto. Este puede llamar incluso con variables que son nulas, en cuyo caso devolverá el String "null"

Espero te ayude :)